# Apache <LocationMatch> order and regexes

Tags: regex, apache, locationmatch

I've trying this for a couple of days and maybe am I wrong in some way. I'm trying to change the header depending on the final url, but the first capture group is always the same, `/folder`, happens that Apache is just using the last rule as I seen on the Apache Documentation seems like is the normal behaviour.

**This is the current scenario:**

I got three urls:

```
/folder
/folder/something
/folder/private
```

`index, follow` must be applied to `/folder` (the root) and `/folder/private` but the other ones must be on `noindex, nofollow`

And these are the regex currently on the configuration:

```
<LocationMatch "^\/(folder)$">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "index, follow"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^\/(folder)\/private(.*)">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "index, follow"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^\/(folder)(.*)">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</LocationMatch>
```

Maybe I'm using a bad regex? Out of ideas...

Thanks!